# Getting HWND from firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, hwnd

I am writing an extension for Firefox, and I need to find out the window's HWND. I can't enumerate running processes or anything like that, as it needs to be able to handle multiple instances and tell one from the other. Is there a way of doing this via a javascript extension in Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible from JavaScript, but it should be possible from a C++ extension.